# How to prompt for an entity with "yes" or "no" question in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an entity "employeeType" in Dialogflow with values as "Federal employee" and "Private Employee".

If the entity data is not obtained, I want to ask user a question "Are you a Federal Employee?" to which user can respond "yes" or "no".

However I am not finding a way to do it since such a question wont return the predefined values "Federal employee" or "Private Employee".

Any thoughts on ways to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my recommended approach:

1. Make an intent which accepts `employeeType` entity but **do not
   mark** it as `required`
2. Turn on the `webhook` for this intent, and **do not** put any
   `fulfillment text`
3. In the webhook check parameter `employeeType` if it contains value
   or its empty
4. If `employeeType` have value, just return a fulfillment text and
   proceed with your flow
5. If `employeeType` is empty, then set output context `emp-followup`
   and put fulfillment text "Are you a Federal Employee?"
6. Make a yes-follow-up intent and a no-follow-up intent for your
   intent with input context `emp-followup` and put fulfillment text in
   those to proceed with your flow

[image: intent set up]

[image: conversation-1]  [image: conversation-2]    [image: conversation-3]

Sample Code:

```
req = request.get_json()
    params = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters')
    if params['employeeType']:
        res = json.dumps({
            "fulfillmentText": "great! welcome sir."
        })
    else:
        res = json.dumps({
            "outputContexts": [
            {
                "name": "{}/contexts/emp-followup".format(req['session']),
                "lifespanCount": 2,
            },
        ],
            "fulfillmentText": "are you a federal employee"
        })
    return res
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. How you approach this depends on how you have other things structured.

Since you have an "employeeType" Entity, you can make `yes` a synonym for the `Federal employee` entity and `no` a synonym for `Private employee`. However, this may make some phrases work oddly, and you should probably add additional aliases for other positive-like and negative-like responses.

You can also just accept these using the Followup Intents, which have yes and no aliases already setup, and in a webhook fulfillment save the value that you want attached to the respective Intent.

Comment: sir, i think making yes/no synonym can have some weird conversation effects as well. might not work.